# Fzaninotto Faker Install package

Tags: php, json, laravel

Can you help me with this error in laravel? I ran `php artisan db:seed --class=UserTableSeeder` and got:

**PHP Fatal error:**

> Class `'Faker\Factory'` not found in /Users/I/Laravel/authapp/app/database/seeds 
>          /UserTableSeeder.php on line 7

```
{
"error":{
    "type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception \\FatalErrorException",
    "message":"Class 'Faker\\Factory' not found",
    "file":"\/Users /I\/Laravel\/authapp\/app\/database\/seeds\/UserTableSeeder.php",
    "line":7
}
}
```

My UserTableSeeder.php

```
<?php
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder 
{

    public function run()  
    {  

        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        User::truncate();

        foreach(range(1,30) as $index)  
        {  
            User::create([  
                'username' => str_replace('.', '_', $faker->unique()->userName),  
                'email' => $faker->email,  
                'password' => 'password', 
            ]);  
        }
    }
}
```

My composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
         "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
  },

}
```

After adding the comma, I still get the same error and If I try to include it using autoload from github it also does not work. Where could I look for the error?

I still get the same error. I am scared that it is not loading the Fzniotto Faker Package. What can I do? If I try to include the package by downlaoding it, I get

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'require_once(../../../vendor/Faker/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /Users/stefanieness/Laravel/authapp/app/database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/stefanieness/Laravel/authapp/app/database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php(6): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'require_once(.....', '/Users/stefanie...', 6, Array)
#1 /Users/stefanieness/Laravel/authapp/app/database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php(6): UserTableSeeder::run()
#2 /Users/stefanieness/Laravel/authapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/SeedCommand.php(57): UserTableSeeder->run()
#3 /Users/stefanieness/Laravel/authapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(112): Illuminate\Database\Console\SeedCommand->fire()
#4 /Users/stefanieness/Laravel/authapp/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), O in /Users/stefanieness/Laravel/authapp/app/database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php on line 6
PHP Fatal error:  UserTableSeeder::run(): Failed opening required '../../../vendor/Faker/autoload.php' (include_path='/Users/stefanieness/Laravel/authapp/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:') in /Users/stefanieness/Laravel/authapp/app/database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php on line 6
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"UserTableSeeder::run(): Failed opening required '..\/..\/..\/vendor\/Faker\/autoload.php' (include_path='\/Users\/stefanieness\/Laravel\/authapp\/vendor\/phpseclib\/phpseclib\/phpseclib:.:')","file":"\/Users\/stefanieness\/Laravel\/authapp\/app\/database\/seeds\/UserTableSeeder.php","line":6}}SEICCN-3:authapp stefanieness$
```

Comment: Did you run ´composer update´?

Comment: Yes, I found the problem:     "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
  }, has to be removed, it was done by autoinstall of composer, otherwise it wont download faker or make an error! And I was also missing Eloquent::unguard(); in the first line of the run function. However, I now no longer get an error, but I also do not get any users in my table. It seems to be simply not working, eg. the table is not created and filled with lorem ipsum users. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

*I still get the same error. I am scared that it is not loading the Fzniotto Faker Package. What can I do?*

In your shell, try running `php artisan dump-autoload`.

---

Run `composer update`, you are however missing a comma in your composer.json;

```
 "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
     "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
}
```

Should be;

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
}
```

If you already have the dependency and copied the code wrong try running `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you forgot a comma

```
 "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
     "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
},
```

then run `composer update`

Answer (score 1):

*However, I now no longer get an error, but I also do not get any users in my table. It seems to be simply not working, eg. the table is not created and filled with lorem ipsum users. What can I do?*

Have you created your users table?

If not you need to;

Run `php artisan migrate:make create_users_table`.

In your `app/database/migrations` folder you will find your new migration file.

Build your migration (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema).

Run `php artisan migrate`.

Run `php artisan db:seed`.

Comment: Hi, I had the table but I needed to open the migration, save it again and then run the db:seed and then it worked :))) THANK YOU SO MUCH!